# css padding causing borders to overlap

Tags: html, css

I have css that adds a border around a list items, but when I add the padding, the list items' borders start crossing over each other. Here is my current css for the Li:

```
.display_times{padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important; font-size: 24px; border:1px solid black; display:inline; }
```

Here's a picture of what it looks like.

[image]

Is there any way to keep the padding but push the borders back so that they are more like this, but with padding:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your HTML too

Comment: did you try to define `display: inline-block; float: left` or `display: block;`?

Comment: what if you create a border around the the list and then had a border-bottom on every list item except the last one?

Comment: @Banzay 'display: inline-block;' worked perfectly for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this css works:

```
.display_times {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important;
  font-size: 24px;
  border:1px solid black; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: may be worth mentioning that this is because non-block level elements (ie. those with  `display:inline`) dont respect top and bottom padding: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/ (links to CSS2 spec in article)

Comment: The  display: inline-block; was what made it work for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: inline-block shouldn't work since all the times would wrap to one line? didn't you need items to display on separate lines?

Comment: @GovindRai, depends on the width of the containing element, if its not wide enough to accommodate more than one per line, only one will exist per line

Comment: @haxxxton true.. but then this example wouldn't work in all cases, especially the example that the poster used when asking the question.. i guess if the poster is happy it's fine lol

Comment: @GovindRai, given OP currently is using `display:inline` and the items are appearing on new lines, it's probably safe to assume that there's a containing element.. but you know what they say about when you assume :P hard to know anything without the html :)

Comment: @GovindRai - for the case the solution depends on context, so I asked possible variants in early comment.

Comment: @haxxxton actually you're very right on that.. didn't think from that perspective at all. Banzay you're in the clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after but:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>10:00</li>
  <li>12:00</li>
  <li>13:00</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border:1px solid black;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:last-child{
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
 }
.last {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<div>11:00</div>
<div>12:00</div>
<div>13:00</div>
<div class="last">14:00</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't Ever use **display:Inline**, if you want to give the elements a specified padding or height, because these properties **doesn't apply to inline**.

You Can Only Set left or right width using Inline, better always use for such situation **inline-block**.